# Code showing error when assigning mx. number of packets to queue

Tags: python, ns-3

The following code shows this error:

```
msg="Invalid attribute set (MaxSize) on ns3::PointToPointNetDevice", file=../src/core/model/object-factory.cc, line=75
terminate called without an active exception
Command ['/usr/bin/python', 'scratch/python_first_mod2.py', '--SimulatorImplementationType=ns3::VisualSimulatorImpl'] terminated with signal SIGIOT. Run it under a debugger to get more information (./waf --run <program> --command-template="gdb --args %s <args>").
```

The code:

```
pointToPoint2.SetQueue ("ns3::DropTailQueue","MaxSize", ns.core.StringValue ("50p"))
pointToPoint2.SetDeviceAttribute("DataRate", ns.core.StringValue ("10Mbps"))
pointToPoint2.SetChannelAttribute("Delay", ns.core.StringValue ("2ms"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating the queue first, set the attribute and then pass the queue to the PointToPoint object via SetQueue().

Your code tries to set the attribute "MaxSize" on  a [ns3::PointToPointNetDevice](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_point_to_point_net_device.html) object. Obviously you try to set the attribute for [ns3::DropTailQueue](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_drop_tail_queue.html) which inherits this attribute from the class [ns3::QueueBase](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_queue_base.html#details).

Comment: But when I use this line :pointToPoint2.SetQueue ("ns3::DropTailQueue","MaxPackets", ns.core.StringValue ("40"))                            It seems to work now.

Comment: ...StringValue ("40") shouldn't be possible, because you don't clarify on the unit to be used. https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_queue_size.html#details